# Creating a mobile App with Laravel and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel-5, single-page-application

I've been reading up on AngularJS lately (always used jQuery) and I'm starting to understand and like it. Normally I would build webapplications with Laravel. Now i'd really like to dig further and learn about connecting these two frameworks to build an awesome SPA. In this case, Laravel serves as a REST api and Angular handles the front end. [This article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application) and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqAyiqUs93c) helped me a lot, but still raises questions.

The biggest one (maybe very stupid) is: could the HTML/CSS/JS be converted to a native mobile app, for example with PhoneGap? Because that is what I'm wishing to achieve if possible.
Also, if this is possible, is it a good way or does it get too tricky?

This is still very new to me, just need some help on the way. I hope my question makes some sence, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would imagine authentication is not very different to how it is now - just submit your credentials via AJAX, and process them in the way Laravel usually does. AJAX requests will still return/set cookies.

Comment: (Your question is rather too broad, and perhaps asks too many sub-questions, and so may end up placed on hold. We prefer less generalised questions here, just so you know).

Comment: You're right, it was too broad, edited. And about the authentication, how could this be secure? Just sending an reponse with status OK and then set a cookie sounds risky.

Comment: If the user meet authorisation requirements, don't send them what they ask for. It's about allowing or denying access to data, which still must come from the server.

Comment: Well acces should be granted with some sort of encrypted token, right?

Comment: If you are going to use angular for a mobile app keep it as a web app and use angular material, take a look at the components: https://material.angularjs.org/ very easy to use and easy to manage different sizes of screens.

Comment: Well, you're already sending a cookie - won't that do? It's not encrypted as such - just a random identifier, usually, set by PHP.